# How to read binary file in Julia?

Tags: julia

I have used Matlab and now try to convert some code to Julia.

```
% Load data in Matlab
fileID = fopen('./data_6000x3199.bin');
Data = fread(fileID,[6000,3199],'single');
fclose(fildID);
```

However, I have no idea how to read this single type binary file in Julia code.
Can someone help this, please?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[`read!`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/io-network/#Base.read!) will fill an array with data read from a binary file:

```
julia> x # original array
2×2 Array{Float32,2}:
 1.0  3.0
 2.0  4.0

julia> write("test.bin", x) # write to binary file
16

julia> y = Array{Float32}(undef, 2, 2); # create a container for reading data

julia> read!("test.bin", y) # read data
2×2 Array{Float32,2}:
 1.0  3.0
 2.0  4.0
```

`'single'` means single precision floating point, which is represented with `Float32` in Julia. Your example MATLAB code will translate to this Julia code:

```
data = Array{Float32}(undef, 6000, 3199)
read!("data_6000x3199.bin", data)
```

Comment: How can I upvote twice? ;) Really useful and came back to the same question and answer!